# How can I have all packages come with Ubuntu on a chroot?

Tags: package-management, chroot

Unfortunately, when I use debootstrap to install a chrooted ubuntu only a set of minimal packages gets installed. What should I do if I want to install all packages that come with Ubuntu?

The reason I am looking to do that is I want to have the a test platform which is as almost exactly as it can be as an Ubuntu.

Comment: `apt install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: What if I want to have only non GUI packages?

Comment: Outside the `chroot` jail, `dpkg --get-selections` will list installed packages. Inside the `chroot` jail `dpkg --set-selections;` will mark them for installations. Or read about the `makejail` command, or `schroot`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nice hack to do that.

1) First, download [runc](https://github.com/Nitrux/runc).

2) Download and extract a small root filesystem, so you can run commands inside it.

```sh
# Run all the following as root.

# Change this to your desire.
BUILD_DIR=$(mktemp -d)
CHROOT_DIR=$BUILD_DIR/root

mkdir -p $CHROOT_DIR
wget -O base.tar.gz http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-base/releases/18.04/release/ubuntu-base-18.04.1-base-amd64.tar.gz

tar xf base.tar.gz -C $CHROOT_DIR
```

3) Use `runc` to install the packages.

```sh
chmod +x runc

runc $CHROOT_DIR apt-get install ubuntu-minimal
```

---

You can use `runc` to run a shell in the `chroot` directory like: `runc $CHROOT_DIR sh`.